# Struct and pointer to pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, dereference

I am learning about linked lists and how to create them in C with structs and pointers. I have an example below. From my understanding the called `push()` passes the beginning memory location of our struct where the head node lies as an argument. The parameter of our push() function takes a struct node as a pointer to pointer so it is passed as a reference, not an actual copy. So the first pointer of our `struct node** headref` is just a pointer to the memory location of our head node and the second pointer points to the value, which is the next memory location that the head node points to. We create a new node called newnode inside our struct node by assigning it some memory. We then create an int type data inside this node.

Okay assuming everything I said is correct, the next part is what i am confused on.

```
newNode->next= *headRef;
```

This line from what i can understand dereferences the `headref` so this would just have the `headref` pointing to the head node. Then we have a pointer operation where what the `headref` is pointing to will then also be what our pointer next will be pointing to. Based on that the pointer next in our new node(`newnode`) will be pointing to the head pointer.

The next line which i am also confused on is:

```
*headRef = newNode;
```

What the dereferenced `headref` pointer is pointing to, which is the head node, will be pointing now to our newnode.

Based on that there should be a new node called newnode with an int data and a next pointer linking our newnode to the head. Then the headref pointer(or is it the head node?) will point to the new node. I know this isn't correct because the pointer next of our newnode should be pointing to the second node so our newnode can be linked in the struct. I also don't believe that i am understanding the pointer to pointer and dereferencing in the above two lines of code.

Code:

```
void Push(struct node** headRef, int data) {
  struct node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  newNode->data = data;
  newNode->next = *headRef;
  *headRef = newNode;
}

void PushTest(void) {
  struct node* head = BuildTwoThree(); // suppose this returns the list {2, 3}

  Push(&head, 1);
  Push(&head, 13);
  // head is now the list {13, 1, 2, 3} 
}
```

Comment: What is the question, exactly?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I can read -- it's kinda hard to write without being able to read to begin with. That question being answered, what I was asking was what your question about those lines was -- is it just a "how does this work?" thing, or is it a "why doesn't it do X?" thing?

Comment: which part of my assumptions are wrong? I am clearly not reading those two lines correctly because what i am thinking doesn't link the head node to the newnode and the next pointer of the newnode to the second node(previously created before we created a newnode to be inserted). Sorry for being rude, just annoyed i can't understand this.

Comment: Apology accepted. I'll post the details about the code in an actual answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void Push(struct node** headRef, int data) {
```

headRef contains an address of address where struct node is located. It is an address of the *head* variable in *PushTest* function.

```
struct node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Here we created a newNode. It contains an address of memory where node struct is located.

```
newNode->data = data;
```

set the data of newNode to the value of the *data* parameter passed into the *Push* function - OK.

```
newNode->next = *headRef;
```

set the *newNode->next*  to the address of the structure located in the *head* variable. For example, if we have written

```
 void Push(struct node* head, int data) {
 ...
 newNode->next = head;
```

Next, we need to change the *head* variable to the *newNode*. If *head* variable was passed by reference, we could simply write this, like in C++:

```
void Push(struct node* &head, int data) {
...
head = newNode;
```

But in plain C we have to pass the address where *head* variable is located, so we can write into that address the pointer to the structure *newNode* we created in the *Push* function:

```
*headRef = newNode;
```

is equivalent to the **write the newNode pointer to the variable whose address is located inside the headRef variable**

And there is a problem in your logic:

> The parameter of our push() function takes a struct node as a pointer
>   to pointer so it is passed as a reference, not an actual copy.

Actually, we pass a **copy** of *temporary* variable that contains an address of *node* variable, not the reference. There is *pass-by-reference* method in C++, it uses ampersand to declare that the variable passed to function is a reference, not a copy of original variable.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I wish i could give everyone best answer but yours is the most detailed one.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually both correct and not correct at the same time. The `push` function adds a new node at the head of the list. After this function is called the new node is the new `head`, and the previous `head` node is now the second (next) node in the list. So your observations are correct, but your conclusion is not.

I recommend you step through the code in a debugger, while watching all pointers and their contents, to see what happens. It might make things clearer for you.

Comment: So can we agree that:
newNode->next = *headRef;
the pointer next is pointing to the head node?
and
*headRef = newNode;
Is what exactly? The head node is now the newnode?

so this just flipped the head and the newnode and because the newnode's pointer next is linked to the head(now the old head) then the new head(previously newnode) is pointing to the first node(old head)?

Comment: @user2122810 `newNode->next` will point to `head`, and then `*headRef = newNode` will make head point to `newNode`. The `head` pointer when this function is called, now points to the new node added. Really, step through the code in a debugger while checking all variables and pointer. It's a great way of seeing what happens "in action".

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I think I can explain.

`head` is the head pointer of linked list. `headRef` points to head. So `*headRef` is head pointer(pass by reference).

so `newNode->next` will now point to head of the struct ( which has value 2, thats why the nodes are getting inserted at front).

Now in this line `*headRef = newNode;`
`*headRef` is assigned the value of `newNode` so the `head` is now changed to `newNode` in the original structure.

Again when you pass `&head`, you are passing the `head` which contains value 1 now.

Comment: The only thing i am confused about what you said is newNode->next. We are derefencing the headRef so now it doesn't point to 2 but to the head only. No?

Comment: headRef does not point to the structure, it only points to the variable that points to that structure. When you dereference it, you get that variable that points to that structure.

Comment: @user2122810 Yes. It points to head. Not 2. To get "2" you have to do *headRef->data

Answer (score 0):

Let's copy this here, for simpler reference:

```
1   void Push(struct node** headRef, int data) {
2     struct node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
3     newNode->data = data;
4     newNode->next = *headRef;
5     *headRef = newNode;
6   }
```

For the sake of simplicity, I numbered the lines.

Now, `headRef` itself is just a pointer to the *variable* that held the header of the list -- therefore, it contains no useful information by itself. By dereferencing that pointer, you're gaining access to the *contents* of the variable itself (`head` in `PushTest()`). Therefore, `*headRef` is essentially the way you get access to  `head`. Now, since `head` is the top node, so is `*headRef` -- they hold the same value, since they are the same address. What line 4 does is, assign the value of `*headRef` (i.e., the value of `head`) to the new node's next link. In the same fashion, line 5 assigns the new node to `*headRef`, which is the same as assigning it to `head`, since `headRef` is a pointer to `head` -- meaning that `*headRef` is the value of `head`.

The key point here is, `headRef` is a reference (a pointer) to `head`, so `*headRef` and `head` are equivalents (scope rules aside).