# Problems with pointers allocation when dynamically build a binary tree in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, binary-tree

studying C for few months, I encounter some difficulties with the use of pointers when dynamically building a binary tree:

Given my code below:

```
typedef struct TNoeud
{
    int data;
    struct TNoeud *pFilsGauche;
    struct TNoeud *pFilsDroit;
} TNoeud;


void insereData(int data, TNoeud **pRacine)
{
    TNoeud *noeud=malloc(sizeof(TNoeud));

    noeud->data=data;
    noeud->pFilsDroit=NULL;
    noeud->pFilsGauche=NULL;

    while((*pRacine)!=NULL)
    {
        if(data<(*pRacine)->data)
        {
            pRacine=&(**pRacine).pFilsGauche;
        }
        else
        {
            pRacine=&(**pRacine).pFilsDroit;
        }
    }
    if(pRacine==NULL)
    {
        *pRacine=noeud;
    }
    free(noeud);
}
```

And in the main:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    TNoeud *pRacine=malloc(sizeof(TNoeud));

    pRacine->data=0;
    pRacine->pFilsGauche=NULL;
    pRacine->pFilsDroit=NULL;

    pRacine=&noeudRacine;

    insereData(4, &pRacine);

    return 0;
}
```

I read the following topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/28637104/7866010 for the BAD_ACCESS, but in my case, the pointer is not at NULL, as pRacine is assigned at 0.

I read the following topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/15154553/7866010 , but it didn't help.

I also tried the declaration variant

```
(*pRacine)->data
```

found in this topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/346739/7866010 without any difference.

So my questions are :

- [SOLVED with TNoeud noeud as pointer instead of local variable. I also changed pRacine in the main the same way] Why do the pointer

  ```
  *pRacine == NULL
  ```

  when I pass a pointer to an assigned value as parameter of

  ```
  insereData(4, &pRacine) ?
  ```
- [SOLVED the same way] Why does the debugger give me random values to pointers

  ```
  [1] = 0x00007fff5fbff700)
  ```

  and datas

  ```
  (int) data = 1606416544)
  ```

  I didn't willingly assigned ?
- [SOLVED: by deleting the `if(pRacine==NULL)` condition and replacing it by just `(*pRacine)=noeud;`] Now no more errors, but the result of

  ```
  insereData(4, &pRacine);
  ```

  doesn't impact pRacine : it should be

  ```
  pRacine->pFilsDroit->data==4
  ```

  but here it remains at NULL. I don't understand why, as it's not a local variable anymore.

Thanks all for your answers!

Comment: `TNoeud noeud;` is local auto variable. Its lifespan is through the scope(only inside function).

Comment: Your variable "TNoeud noeud" disappears as soon as the function it is defined in exits. Any pointer that used to point to it now points to a black hole. Any attempt to examine such pointer leads to a violation of the laws of physics. This is all explained im any C book. Get one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions(not law).
First in order to not confuse yourself about pointers, just work with them as arrays. it really works and won't confuse you.
For instance given pointer `int* ptr`, for accessing the first element go as `ptr[0]`.

And the problem is here

```
if(pRacine==NULL)
    {
        *pRacine=&noeud;
    }
```

as the `noeud` is not in dynamic memory, it gets halted.
You simply need to define the `noeud` as a pointer of the struct by `malloc`. But for memory sake, please keep an eye for `free` it once it's not needed.

Comment: Ok, I edited it in my question to `TNoeud *noeud=malloc(sizeof(TNoeud));` and `free(noeud);`.

Comment: @dxp very awesome you could fix the problem yourself, perfect. Just one note again, please have an eye over `malloc` all the time. becasue you need to `free` the allocated memory yourself once it's not required.